# support time namespace for ubuntu with systemd use

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, daemons

I have *Ubuntu 21.04*, and need to support *systemd* for minikube use.

For `minikube` support, which needs the systemd (also calls systemctl), I found a workaround solution for adding systemd deamon support in:

[minikube for ubuntu](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop/)

When trying running any script related to: daemonize,
and running `/usr/bin/nsenter -t "$SYSTEMD_PID" -a`, I got and error:

> cannot open /proc/27791/ns/time: No such file or directory

I investigated a bit, and find in: [linux namespace](https://www.csa.iisc.ac.in/%7Evg/teaching/E0-256/slides/lxc-slide-deck.pdf) that (as in the link):

> Time (CLONE_NEWTIME; /proc/pid/ns/time) <= very new!

I assume it is new namespace with new support, so there might be an installation, whenever I need to downgrade or having upgrade of a version for a specific installation.

Whether is *deamonatize* service or another service.

when running `lsns -l` I get:

[image: list of namespaces]

I see there is no namespace of *time*.

What should I do in order to support /proc/pid/ns/time (or downgrade/upgrade a specific version - how can I do that)?

Thanks.